# Test if the decimal digits of $n$ appear $n$ times in the decimal representation of $n!$

Tags: performance-tuning, number-theory, digits

I want to find numbers $n$ for which the decimal digits of $n$ appear $n$ times in the decimal representation of $n!$.

For instance, $n\in\left\{0, 1, 1170, 1528, 9877, 9886, 9897, 11535\right\}$ are known to have this property.

I came up with the following code:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
k = Factorial[n];
p = IntegerDigits[k];
n = 0;
Monitor[Parallelize[
  While[True, 
   If[n == Length[p] - 
      Length[p /. Thread[IntegerDigits[n] -> Nothing]], Print[n]]; 
   n++]; n], n]
```

This becomes pretty slow after some time (for $n\ge200000$). Is there a faster way?

Comment: Just so I understand, can you explain how 1170 is a solution? I would have guessed that this means that the sequence 1,1,7,0 appears 1170 times in 1170!. But I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Oh, I see. So if I add up the number of 1s, 7s, and 0s in 1170! I get 1170.

Comment: @lericr indeed that is the case.

Comment: So, what kind of timings are you getting so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

20000 in 21 seconds.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 0;
k := Factorial[n];
p := IntegerDigits[k];
Do[
 co = Counts[p];
 If[Total[
    Table[co[[Key[i]]], {i, DeleteDuplicates[IntegerDigits[n]]}]] == 
   n, Print[n]];
 n++, 20000]
```

In red, points (some overlapping) where the difference between the sum of digits and n is 0. Interesting pattern.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is an attempt:

```
IsSpecial[n_Integer] :=
  With[
    {uniqueDigits = DeleteDuplicates[IntegerDigits[n]]},
    n == Count[IntegerDigits[n!], Alternatives @@ uniqueDigits]];
AbsoluteTiming[Select[Range@20000, IsSpecial]]
(* {95.4927, {1, 1170, 1528, 9877, 9886, 9897, 11535}} *)
```

When I ran your code, it took 256 seconds to test the first 20,000 integers. (I didn't have the patience to go to 200000 given that result for 20000.)

Comment: I'm thinking one optimization would be to not check all of the training 0s.